# Can I Convert Code Write on Win8 on Visual Studio into Win 7

Tags: visual-studio

I get a project code from others,

(the code is written by Visual studio on Win 8.1)

then I open the code on my computer which is Win 7, and VS shows:

```
 This computer must be upgraded to windows 8.1 to load this project.
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XKmnBww.png]

Is there any way to solve this problem except upgrade my computer to Win 8.1,

such as some method to convert the code from Win8 to Win7?

Comment: If this is Windows store app you really need Windows 8.1 or higher

Comment: may be some components are not supported in the downgraded version..We can convert code ,but what about frameworks or other components that depend on the machine O.S ?